# Calculate Time Complexity

Tags: time, complexity-theory

Calculate number of step and time complexity for equation:

T(n) = 2 T(n/4) + 5 where n > 1, T (1) = 1

What is the Big O Notation?

Comment: This isn't a homework-answering service. I don't think StackOverflow wants to be filled with millions of algorithms with people asking what their Big O is.  It doesn't help the community.

Comment: Google *Master theorem*.

Answer (score 0):

Your second step is not correct. You have to replace the T(n/4) term and not just add to the end of your equation. That way you get:

T(n) = 2T(n/4) + 5

= 2(2T(n/16)+5)+5 = 2²T(n/16) + (2¹+1)*5

= 2²(2T(n/64)+5) + (2¹+1)*5 = 2³T(n/64) + (2³+1)*5

= 2³(2T(n/256)+5) + (2³+1)*5 = 2⁴T(n/256) + (2⁶+1)*5